# dropdown value is not selected after loading a partial view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two partial views in the parent view. In the parent view there is a "div" tag that holds a partial view called "state".

```
<div id="divState"></div></td>
```

The partial view just has a DDL in it:

```
@Html.DropDownList("State", null, "---------- Select ----------", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The partial view is loading like below:

```
$('#divState').load('@Url.Action("LoadState", "General")');
```

Controller code is like below:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult LoadState()
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                ViewBag.State = new SelectList(db.Generals, "IID", "Value");
                return PartialView("_State");
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I have a link button that is opening a modal dialogbox, which is actually a partial view. The partial view holds a couple of fields and a button for saving data. After saving the value will be shown in the state DDL with the last entered value. I have written the following jQuery to store and select the last inserted value.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#btnSave").click(function () {
                    debugger;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("SaveGeneralData", "General")',
                        data: '{name:"' + $("#Value").val() + '", description:"' + $("#Description").val() + '"}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            //alert("Id :" + response.IID);
                            var id = response.IID;
                            $('#divState').load('@Url.Action("LoadState", "General")');// Loading the partial view from controller
// to get the newly inserted value
                            $('#dialogState').dialog('close');
                            //$('div#divState select').val("5").attr("selected", "selected");
                            $("div#divState select").val("5");
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                            //alert("1");
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
```

After inserting value is showing in the DDL as I am reloading the partial view that holds the DDL.
But my problem is that the last inserted value is not selected. DDL is displaying the first list item after flashing the last insert record (i.e it is hard-coded as "5").

Any help will be thankfully accepted.
Partha

Comment: What is your element with `id="btnSave"`?

Comment: "btnSave" is actually the save button in the partial view that holds a couple of fields. Those values will be saved in the database and also stored in the DDL(also within a partial view i.e. 'state'). The saved values are returning from the controller through json. Values are captured through a javascript which is already given.

Comment: type is "button".

Comment: <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span></button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax calls are async, and your `$("div#divState select").val("5");` line of code is executed before the `.load()` function has completed.

You need to set the value of the `<select>` in the success callback

```
success: function (response) {
    ...
    $('#divState').load('@Url.Action("LoadState", "General")', function() {
        // set value in the callback (after the DOM has been updated)
        $("div#divState select").val("5");
    });
},
```

However, its unclear why your making an ajax call to replace the `<select>` again. If the first ajax call is saving data to your `Generals` table, so you need to update the options, then your first call should be returning the `IID` and `Value` in your `JsonResult`, and then you can just create and append a new `<option>` element to the existing `<select>`

Comment: I am using a partial view and not an ajax form. Parent form will be saved later. I am not using ajax form. How can I call success callback in partial view. I am reloading the partial view because there is an order by clause to maintain the sequence.

Comment: Who said you were using an ajax form? And you can order it with javascript anyway. Did you even try the correct code I gave you? - you just replace the code in your existing `success: function (response) { ... }` with the code in my answer